# How can I prove that column space of $A^2$ contained in the column space of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ is a square matrix.
Looks like I have to use a property that $N(A)$ is contained in $N(A^2)$ but I'm lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$C(A^2)=\{b:x,b\in\mathbb R^n, A^2x=b\}$$
$$C(A)=\{b:x,b\in\mathbb R^n, Ax=b\}$$
Now, if $b\in C(A^2)$, there exists $x\in\mathbb R^n$ such that
$$A^2x=b$$
$$A(Ax)=b\text{ ,where }Ax\in\mathbb R^n$$
$$b\in C(A)$$

Thus, whenever $b\in C(A^2)$, we have $b\in C(A)$. Thus,
$$C(A^2)\subseteq C(A)$$

Comment: I understood above "Now, if b ~ ". But not sure how if I can write A^2*x = b

Comment: @user325050 That is by definition of the column space.

Comment: Okay, got it. thx

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

> The column space of a matrix $A$ is the image (range) of the corresponding matrix transformation.

This means that $A(x)$ is an element of the column space for all $x \in V$.

Now what about?
$$
A^2(x)=A(A(x))
$$